# How to solve "notice array to string conversion in C" error in php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, datatables

So I am trying to send the "id" of a selected row in datatable in javascript to a php page so I could delete it from database.

```
var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
    return item[0]  });
```

the variable "ids" is sent by post method

`$.post( "deleterow.php", { v1: ids });`

but it didn't worked so i try to see the response from post method and it says 
"notice array to string conversion in C on line ... "
the line is of php page where i am writing the delete query

```
$id = $_POST["v1"];
$query = "DELETE FROM `package` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
```

The whole php page works fine when trying with other values.

Comment: You are sending an array (`map` returns an array) to your PHP page, and then you're trying to concatenate it with a string, which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you send an array here:

```
$.post( "deleterow.php", { v1: ids });
```

so `v1` contains an array of elements. But in your php code you treat it as a single element:

```
$id = $_POST["v1"];
```

Hence the `notice array to string conversion`.

If you send an array of elements, you have to get it as an array and treat is as an array. To create a correct SQL string you should append each ID, like this:

```
$ids = json_decode($_POST["v1"]);
$query = "DELETE FROM `package` WHERE";
$first = true;
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    if ($first) {
        $first = false;
    } else {
        $query += " OR";
    }
    $query += " `id` = '$id'"
}
```

This way you loop the array and append a `id = ID` for each array element.

Now, **this is important**, this code is prone to SQL injection, a really bad security problem. Read this to get more info about this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)